# How to change a symbol within a character string [R]

Tags: r, rename

I have many elements in a column in the format:

```
Var.24.22918699
```

Which need to be changed to

```
Var-24-22918699
```

Is there an easy way to do this R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There sure is.  `gsub` is used to replace specific characters in a string using regular expressions.

```
> x <- "Var.24.22918699"    
> gsub("[.]", "-", x)
## [1] "Var-24-22918699"
```

Comment: Perhaps faster: `gsub(".", "-", x, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: One could also use escapes `\\.`

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
x <- "Var.24.22918699"  
chartr('.', '-', x)
# [1] "Var-24-22918699"
```